# Preorder traversal, inorder traversal, postorder traversal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

a) preorder traversal

b) inorder traversal

c) postorder traversal

### [image]

Ok,

a) r,j,h,g,e,d,b,a,c,f,i,k,m,p,s,n,q,t,v,w,u

b) a,b,d,c,e,g,f,h,j,i,r,s,p,m,k,n,v,t,w,q,u

c) a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,v,w,t,u,q,n,s,p,m,k,r

I'm definitely doing some mistakes here, but that was my try.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your preorder looks good. Your inorder should start with h. Your postorder was good for the left half, but after j should come s.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Pre-order traversal is root; left; right
so your preorder is ok.  r, j, h, g, e, d, b, a, c, f, i, k, m, p, s, n, q, t, v, w, u

The in-order traversal is left; root; right.
I have 
h, e, a, b, d, c, g, f, j, i, r, m, s, p, k, n, v, t, w, q, u
so your in-order is definitely wrong.

Post order: left; right; root
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, s, p, m, v, w, t, u, q, n, k, r

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fixed, thanks.